# How to get GET request using chrome api

Tags: google-chrome, webrequest

[image]

Is it possible to get the value of `is_digg`. this is what I have tried:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(

function(details) {
console.log(details);
},
{urls: \["*://*.tiktok.com/\*"]},\["blocking", "requestHeaders"\]);
```